# Search from Right in string and stop at specific char

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Lets say i have the strings

```
G:\Test\Man\Wife\photo.jpg
C:\Folder\simple\why.jpg
blablabla\\skjflka\yes\no\yeeha
```

I Need to read the string from right to left and stop at the first `\`

result should be

```
photo.jpg
why.jpg
yeeha
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Which database server you are using

Comment: SQL SERVER 2014

Answer (score 5):

The last position of a character is the first position of it within the reversed string so:

```
select 
right(path, charindex('\', reverse('\' + path)) - 1) 
from t
```

(prepend a `\` to allow for file names only)

Comment: I like this one. It's simpler than mine

Comment: Get this error message 402 The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator

Comment: @user2210516 jeezus, you are using `ntext`?, you shouldn't. Anyway, you'll need to convert it first, replace `path` with `CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),path)`

Comment: @user2210516 The NText datatype is deprecated. It will be removed from future versions of SQL Server. Read this here: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms187993.aspx). Use the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` datatype instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REVERSE` and `CHARINDEX`:

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(100);
SET @A = 'C:\Folder\simple\why.jpg';

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@A)+'\',CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@A)+'\')-1)) Result;
```